# Scroll and Zoom using SurfaceView android

Tags: android

I am implementing a simple paint application (Finger paint android). I would like to use two fingers for both scaling and zooming. Should I use different listeners and detectors for both. The problem is that when i try to scroll with two fingers zooming kicks in and the screen just jumps. Can you please point me to implementations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScaleGestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) to easily detect things like pinch-to-zoom. Go through this [Android developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) for a detailed explanation.